# Question regarding the asymptotic values of out-of-time order correlators (OTOCs)

Tags: density-operator, research-level, correlation-functions, ads-cft

Quoting [A bound on chaos](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01409) by Maldacena, Shenker and Stanford:

> Strong chaos, the butterfly effect, is a ubiquitous phenomenon in physical systems, explaining thermal behavior, among other things. In quantum mechanics, this phenomenon
> can be characterized using the commutator $[W(t), V (0)]$ between rather general Hermitian
> operators at time separation $t$. The commutator diagnoses the effect of perturbations by $V$ on later measurements of $W$ and vice versa. One indication of the strength of such
> effects is
> $$C(t) = −\left<[W(t), V (0)]^2\right>$$
> where $\left<\cdot\right> = Z^{-1}\text{tr}[e^{-\beta H}\cdot]$
> denotes the thermal expectation value at temperature $T =\beta^{-1}$. A quantum definition of the butterfly effect is that $C(t)$ should become of order $2\left<W^2\right>\left<V^2\right>$for large $t$, regardless of the specific choice of $V,W$ within an appropriate class.

My problem is that I don't quite understand how the authors have derived the asymptotic value
$$C(t\rightarrow\infty)=2\left<W^2\right>\left<V^2\right>$$
and they don't provide references either. I want to understand how can we derive this asymptotic value, what are the assumptions we need regarding the operators, and how does this fact signal the butterfly effect?

Comment: I think this is probably assuming $\langle V\rangle = \langle W \rangle = 0$.

Comment: @jacob1729 I also suspect that, but I couldn't prove it myself.